# Understanding solution to differential equation in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mathematical-expressions

I got a solution using DSolve as :

```
Function[{t}, -((
   1. (2. + k (-1. - 2. t) + k^2 (-0.5 + 1. t + 1. t^2)))/k^3) + 
  E^(-1. k t) C[1]]
```

What does '.' mean and '()'?  For example, in the case of '2.+k(-1.-2.t)', what does it mean?
How to translate it to normal Math notation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty simple because the first one is regularly used in languages like C and Java too and the second one actually *is* math-notation. Therefore,

- `1.` just means `1.0`. In programming languages this is different from a simple `1` which usually means an integer while `1.0` means a real number. In *Mathematica* a 1 is a perfect *one* with infinite precision, while `1.0` has only machine precision.
- `k(1-t)` just means `k*(1-t)`. Parenthesis are used like in normal math too.